# Uploading a zip from from Blazor WASM app to AWS-S3 - tutorials followed and no errors observed, but also no file in the bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WASM app (i.e., client side) that users upload some data to.  After some sanity and security checks on the data, I would like to upload these to a zip file in AWS S3.

Currently I have constructed the zip file as follows

```cs
using (var outStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(outStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        foreach (var file in imagelist.Files)
        {
            json_name = file.Name + ".json";
            var file_in_archive = archive.CreateEntry(file.Name, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
            using (var entryStream = file_in_archive.Open())
            {
                file.Data.CopyToAsync(entryStream);
            }
            file_in_archive = archive.CreateEntry(json_name, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
            using (var entryStream = file_in_archive.Open())
            {
                formMems[file_counter].CopyToAsync(entryStream);
            }
            file_counter = file_counter + 1;
        }

    }
    Console.WriteLine("Finished zipping");
    uploader.UploadZipFile(outStream, "test_title.zip");
}
```

And I am trying to upload the zip file via this method `uploader.UploadZipFile` - the code is given below

```cs
public class UploadZip    
{
    public BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("access key", "secret key");
 
    public void UploadZipFile(Stream zip_file, string file_name)
    {
        zip_file.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var config = new AmazonS3Config
        {
            RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.Region
        };
        using var client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, config);
        var uploadRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
        {
            InputStream = zip_file,
            Key = file_name,
            BucketName = "Bucket-Name",
            CannedACL = S3CannedACL.Private
        };
        var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(client);
        fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(uploadRequest);
        Console.WriteLine("finshed uploading");
    }
}
```

(uploader is an instance of UploadZip).  I have removed the bucket name, region, access key and secret key for obvious reasons, but these are correct.

The Access Key and the Secret Key belong to a custom IAM user I made just for this purpose.  The Policy summary is given below

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::Bucket-Name/*"
    }
]
```

}

And the S3 bucket has `Block *all* public access` turned **off**, the CORS is given below

```
[
{
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "PUT",
        "POST"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": []
}
```

]

The ACL grants the Bucket owner (your AWS account) *List* and *Write* for **Objects**, and *Read* and *Write* for **Bucket ACL**, with nothing else for the other 3 grantees.  There is no bucket ploicy.

I simply don't understand why this isn't working.  When I run the program I see no errors and the two `Console.write()` calls run fine.

***edit***

In response to advice from a comment, I tried running the code with `Upload` rather than `UploadAsync` - see below

```cs
public class UploadZip    
{
    public BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("AKIAZWFJ7CFNER3WG5EP", "EE9eMD/vz8G3Ui3/MZdGDNBY9xv4+/3y0VQAhNzn");
 
    public void UploadZipFile(Stream zip_file, string file_name)
    {
        zip_file.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var config = new AmazonS3Config
        {
            RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest2
        };
        using var client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, config);
        var uploadRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
        {
            InputStream = zip_file,
            Key = file_name,
            BucketName = "web-pupil-data-store",
            CannedACL = S3CannedACL.Private
        };
        var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(client);
        fileTransferUtility.Upload(uploadRequest);
        Console.WriteLine("finshed uploading");
    }
}
```

This still completes the zipping of the files, but before printing `finished uploading`, it now throws an error with a large and quite inpenetrable (for me) stack trace, copied here

```
blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Cannot start threads on this runtime.
System.NotSupportedException: Cannot start threads on this runtime.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Threading.Thread.Thread_internal(System.Threading.Thread,System.MulticastDelegate)
  at System.Threading.Thread.StartInternal (System.Object principal, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) <0x47bb958 + 0x00008> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Thread.Start (System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) <0x47bb818 + 0x0004e> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Thread.Start () <0x47bb6d8 + 0x0000e> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.BackgroundDispatcher`1[T]..ctor (System.Action`1[T] action) [0x0005c] in D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\trebuchet-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Internal\Util\Dispatcher.cs:55 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.BackgroundInvoker..ctor () [0x00000] in D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\trebuchet-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Internal\Util\Dispatcher.cs:180 
  at Amazon.Util.AWSSDKUtils.get_Dispatcher () [0x00007] in D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\trebuchet-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Util\AWSSDKUtils.cs:674 
  at Amazon.Util.AWSSDKUtils.InvokeInBackground[T] (System.EventHandler`1[TEventArgs] handler, T args, System.Object sender) [0x0004c] in D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\trebuchet-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Util\AWSSDKUtils.cs:661 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.StreamReadTracker.ReadProgress (System.Int32 bytesRead) [0x00047] in D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\trebuchet-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Internal\StreamReadTracker.cs:55 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.EventStream.ReadAsync (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 count, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0009c] in D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\trebuchet-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Internal\Util\EventStream.cs:138 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.ChunkedUploadWrapperStream.FillInputBufferAsync (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00090] in D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\trebuchet-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Internal\Util\ChunkedUploadWrapperStream.cs:189 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.ChunkedUploadWrapperStream.ReadAsync (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 count, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00053] in D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\trebuchet-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Internal\Util\ChunkedUploadWrapperStream.cs:163 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () <0x370ff80 + 0x00034> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.Stream.CopyToAsyncInternal (System.IO.Stream destination, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x36ee098 + 0x00134> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.LoadIntoBufferAsyncCore (System.Threading.Tasks.Task serializeToStreamTask, System.IO.MemoryStream tempBuffer) <0x49ea648 + 0x00110> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.WaitAndReturnAsync[TState,TResult] (System.Threading.Tasks.Task waitTask, TState state, System.Func`2[T,TResult] returnFunc) <0x49eba60 + 0x000c2> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.WebAssemblyHttpHandler.doFetch (System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1[TResult] tcs, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x47cfe90 + 0x0038c> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.WebAssemblyHttpHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x47af880 + 0x00174> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] sendTask, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts, System.Boolean disposeCts) <0x49ef528 + 0x00134> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Amazon.Runtime.HttpWebRequestMessage.GetResponseAsync (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0003d] in D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\trebuchet-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\HttpHandler\_netstandard\HttpRequestMessageFactory.cs:520 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpHandler`1[TRequestContent].InvokeAsync[T] (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00201] in D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\trebuchet-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\HttpHandler\HttpHandler.cs:183 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RedirectHandler.InvokeAsync[T] (Amazon.Runtime.IExecutionContext executionContext) [0x00036] in D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\trebuchet-stage-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\RedirectHandler.cs:59 
  at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.U
f.printErr  @   blazor.webassembly.js:1
f.preRun.push.window.Blazor._internal.dotNetCriticalError   @   blazor.webassembly.js:1
_mono_wasm_invoke_js_unmarshalled   @   dotnet.3.2.0.js:1
do_icall    @   00755c3a:0x10f924
do_icall_wrapper    @   00755c3a:0x50b6a
interp_exec_method  @   00755c3a:0x2588e
interp_runtime_invoke   @   00755c3a:0xf7391
mono_jit_runtime_invoke @   00755c3a:0xddb3d
do_runtime_invoke   @   00755c3a:0x3ba85
mono_runtime_try_invoke @   00755c3a:0xcfdb
try_invoke_perform_wait_callback    @   00755c3a:0xb62e0
worker_callback @   00755c3a:0x9a7a3
fire_tp_callback    @   00755c3a:0x105481
mono_background_exec    @   00755c3a:0xeb5ee
Module._mono_background_exec    @   dotnet.3.2.0.js:1
pump_message    @   dotnet.3.2.0.js:1
setTimeout (async)      
_schedule_background_exec   @   dotnet.3.2.0.js:1
mono_threads_schedule_background_job    @   00755c3a:0x14dbd
ves_icall_System_Threading_ThreadPool_RequestWorkerThread   @   00755c3a:0xa0025
ves_icall_System_Threading_ThreadPool_RequestWorkerThread_raw   @   00755c3a:0x9fecf
do_icall    @   00755c3a:0x10f790
do_icall_wrapper    @   00755c3a:0x50b6a
interp_exec_method  @   00755c3a:0x2588e
interp_runtime_invoke   @   00755c3a:0xf7391
mono_jit_runtime_invoke @   00755c3a:0xddb3d
do_runtime_invoke   @   00755c3a:0x3ba85
mono_runtime_try_invoke @   00755c3a:0xcfdb
mono_runtime_invoke @   00755c3a:0x44b39
mono_wasm_invoke_method @   00755c3a:0xca6a7
Module._mono_wasm_invoke_method @   dotnet.3.2.0.js:1
call_method @   dotnet.3.2.0.js:1
(anonymous) @   dotnet.3.2.0.js:1
endInvokeJSFromDotNet   @   blazor.webassembly.js:1
(anonymous) @   blazor.webassembly.js:1
Promise.then (async)        
beginInvokeJSFromDotNet @   blazor.webassembly.js:1
_mono_wasm_invoke_js_marshalled @   dotnet.3.2.0.js:1
do_icall    @   00755c3a:0x10f8b1
do_icall_wrapper    @   00755c3a:0x50b6a
interp_exec_method  @   00755c3a:0x2588e
interp_runtime_invoke   @   00755c3a:0xf7391
mono_jit_runtime_invoke @   00755c3a:0xddb3d
do_runtime_invoke   @   00755c3a:0x3ba85
mono_runtime_invoke_checked @   00755c3a:0x96a2
mono_runtime_try_invoke_array   @   00755c3a:0x66c26
ves_icall_InternalInvoke    @   00755c3a:0xb44ff
ves_icall_InternalInvoke_raw    @   00755c3a:0xb3ffd
do_icall    @   00755c3a:0x10f8b1
do_icall_wrapper    @   00755c3a:0x50b6a
interp_exec_method  @   00755c3a:0x2588e
interp_runtime_invoke   @   00755c3a:0xf7391
mono_jit_runtime_invoke @   00755c3a:0xddb3d
do_runtime_invoke   @   00755c3a:0x3ba85
mono_runtime_try_invoke @   00755c3a:0xcfdb
mono_runtime_invoke @   00755c3a:0x44b39
mono_wasm_invoke_method @   00755c3a:0xca6a7
Module._mono_wasm_invoke_method @   dotnet.3.2.0.js:1
call_method @   dotnet.3.2.0.js:1
(anonymous) @   dotnet.3.2.0.js:1
beginInvokeDotNetFromJS @   blazor.webassembly.js:1
s   @   blazor.webassembly.js:1
e.invokeMethodAsync @   blazor.webassembly.js:1
(anonymous) @   blazor.webassembly.js:1
t.dispatchEvent @   blazor.webassembly.js:1
(anonymous) @   blazor.webassembly.js:1
(anonymous) @   blazor.webassembly.js:1
e.onGlobalEvent @   blazor.webassembly.js:1
```

Please advise on what further tests I need to do to determine what the problem is, and how I can fix.

***Edit and update***

Following from one of the answers below, I switched to using a `PutObjectRequest`.  The code is below.  This now gives a new error, which I assume is to do with the permissions of the S3 bucket.  Can anyone guide on what I need to change?

**Code**

```
public class UploadData
{
    private readonly BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("access key", "secret Key");

    public async Task UploadZipFile(Stream zip_file, string file_name)
    {
        zip_file.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var config = new AmazonS3Config
        {
            RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest2
        };
        using var client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, config);

        var putRequest1 = new PutObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = "Bucket_name",
            Key = file_name,
            InputStream = zip_file
        };
        PutObjectResponse response1 = await client.PutObjectAsync(putRequest1);

        Console.WriteLine("finshed uploading");
    }
}
```

And here is the error code

```
Unknown encountered on server. Message:'TypeError: Failed to execute 'append' on 'Headers': Invalid value' when putting an object
```

Comment: If you call `Upload()` rather than `UploadAsync()`, does it complete?

Comment: I have edited the question to show behaviour with this change implemented.

Comment: Generally, it is better to instantiate the `AmazonS3Client` as a class field (preferably even as a singleton) as it is somewhat of an expensive operation...

Comment: I can do that, I think, but do you think that will resolve the upload issues?  It seems to me that the core functionality will remain the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know much about blazor and webassembly in particular, but I can give try and give you an advice what I would try:

1. It looks like the issue in the code above is a lack of multithreading support in webassembly, see also [1].
2. The *TransferUtility* class in the aws-sdk-net makes use of threads for multipart uploads, see [2]:

> TransferUtility provides a simple API for uploading content to and downloading content from Amazon S3. It makes extensive use of Amazon S3 multipart uploads to achieve enhanced throughput, performance, and reliability.
>
> When uploading large files by specifying file paths instead of a stream, TransferUtility uses multiple threads to upload multiple parts of a single upload at once. When dealing with large content sizes and high bandwidth, this can increase throughput significantly.

Thus, I would try to use some of the low-level constructs to accomplish a standard upload using *PutObjectRequest*, see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/upload-objects.html

If the files to be uploaded are not too large, this should work without any issues because it is a single-threaded approach.

Another issue would be to enable multi-threading in Blazor WASM, but I am not sure if that is already an option, see [3].

[1] https://www.meziantou.net/don-t-freeze-ui-while-executing-cpu-intensive-work-in-blazor-webassembly.htm
[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/TTransferUtility.html
[3] https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17730

Comment: Okay, I will try these things.  A question, though.  That example also uses await-async.  SHould I be writing that out?

Comment: Okay, I have made progress, in as much as I have a new error!  I have updated the question and given you the bounty.  Thank you.  If you have any other ideas please help me!

Comment: Nice to hear that you made progress @Pablo! Yes, the new error looks like a permission issue. You could use the following tool to figure out the permissions required: https://github.com/iann0036/iamlive

How does your IAM policy for the application look like?

Comment: More progress - I've updated the question, but now I am stuck again - I'm finding it difficult to find any references to this error code.  Any ideas?

Comment: Honestly, I do not know... What are the values you pass as BucketName and Key? Maybe some of them are not allowed?! It is hard to find anything useful here. Which component is throwing the exception? Stacktrace?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no stacktrace, I guess because the error seems to be a server-side error.  I will see if there if I can dig a little deeper.  However, I think it may be best to accept this answer and then ask a new question?  Certainly seems like we have made progress.  Do you agree?