# Error using presigned URL for uploading data from Blazor WASM app to AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have followed and then modified the code given in the following sources

[Lambda code](https://github.com/aws-samples/s3-to-lambda-patterns/blob/master/videos-samples/5-s3-uploader/app.js)

[Front end code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html)

[CORS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/uploading-to-amazon-s3-directly-from-a-web-or-mobile-application/)

[General walkthrough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mw_-0iCVpUc&t=1s)

But when I try and upload an image using the code below...

```
public void UploadObject(Stream jpeg_image)
{
    var buffer = new byte[8000];
    HttpWebRequest httpRequest = WebRequest.Create(URL) as HttpWebRequest;
    httpRequest.Method = "PUT";
    using (Stream dataStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = jpeg_image.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            dataStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
    HttpWebResponse response = httpRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
}
```

I get hit with the following error from the console in my Blazor web page

```
blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
          Unhandled exception rendering component: Operation is not supported on this platform.
    System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
      at System.Net.WebProxy.CreateDefaultProxy () <0x366ff48 + 0x00008> in <filename unknown>:0 
      at System.Net.Configuration.DefaultProxySectionInternal.GetSystemWebProxy () <0x366fe28 + 0x00000> in <filename unknown>:0 
      at System.Net.Configuration.DefaultProxySectionInternal.GetDefaultProxy_UsingOldMonoCode () <0x366fd80 + 0x00000> in <filename unknown>:0 
      at System.Net.Configuration.DefaultProxySectionInternal.GetSection () <0x366fb80 + 0x0002a> in <filename unknown>:0 
      at System.Net.WebRequest.get_InternalDefaultWebProxy () <0x366f8c8 + 0x00034> in <filename unknown>:0 
      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest..ctor (System.Uri uri) <0x366d198 + 0x000b6> in <filename unknown>:0 
      at System.Net.HttpRequestCreator.Create (System.Uri uri) <0x366c7d8 + 0x00004> in <filename unknown>:0 
      at System.Net.WebRequest.Create (System.Uri requestUri, System.Boolean useUriBase) <0x366b498 + 0x00116> in <filename unknown>:0 
      at System.Net.WebRequest.Create (System.String requestUriString) <0x366b0e0 + 0x00024> in <filename unknown>:0 
      at ----.UploadPresigned.UploadObject (System.IO.Stream jpeg_image) [0x0000c] in C:\Users\----\Documents\----\----\DataForm.cs:78 
      at ----.Pages.DataUpload.HandleValidSubmit () [0x002b6] in C:\Users\----\Documents\----\----\Pages\DataUpload.razor:252 
      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x36b85b0 + 0x000da> in <filename unknown>:0 
      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask (System.Threading.Tasks.Task taskToHandle) <0x30d7510 + 0x000b6> in <filename unknown>:0
```

For clarity, line 78 is the following line

```
HttpWebRequest httpRequest = WebRequest.Create(URL) as HttpWebRequest;
```

Note that I've put dashes in the stacktrace to preserve personal information.

I've previously been notified that multi-threaded things don't work will in Blazor (see comments to an answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67892551/uploading-a-zip-from-from-blazor-wasm-app-to-aws-s3-tutorials-followed-and-no) as well as this thread from [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17730) so I'm hypothesising that the problem might be coming from the httpRequest having some multi-threaded backend, since the final two lines in the stack trace mention the System.Threading library.

This [link here](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/295) seems to have a similar issue, but I'm not sure how to port the fix to my code.  I have included the project file below

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
    <RazorLangVersion>3.0</RazorLangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.Core" Version="3.5.3.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.S3" Version="3.5.9.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="3.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Build" Version="3.2.1" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="3.2.1" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IO.Compression.ZipFile" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="3.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="BlazorInputFile" Version="0.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Any advice on how to fix this error?  Please let me know if I need to provide more information on how my app works.